# filter paragraphs from a XML using PHP and HTMLPurifier, SimpleXmlElement or DOM

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I'm trying to remove the social media buttons, leaving only the paragraphs, from the description field of this XML [here](http://www.tst.jus.br/noticias/-/journal/rss/57294?doAsGroupId=10157&refererPlid=10730&_15_groupId=10157) (it's just too big to post here).

Edit: Since some of you couldn't access the XML, follow part of one of the description tags:

```
    <description>
 <!-- TWITTER https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet --> <script> document.write('<a href="https://www.twitter.com/tst_oficial" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-lang="pt">Seguir</a>'); !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
 <!-- CURTIR SITE FACEBOOK (Enviar) --> <iframe class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/TSTJus&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&width=25&height=25&locale=pt_BR" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:0px; margin-left:30px; overflow:hidden; width:120px; height:25px;vertical-align:bottom;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
 <!-- GOOGLE PLUS +1--> <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script> 
 <g:plusone size="medium" href="https://plus.google.com/103151838647081346830" style="border-left:-200px"></g:plusone>
 </div> </br></br> 
 <div class="modelo_noticia">
  <div>
   <div style="float: left; width:47%; text-align:center; margin: 0 9px 0 0;"><a href="/image/journal/article?img_id=5733388&t=1377023456174" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;"><img src="/image/journal/article?img_id=5733388&t=1377023456174" style="margin: 0 5px; width:98%;"/><span style="font-style:italic;"></span> </a></div>
   <p> &nbsp;</p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">"A CLT continua atual enq...a.</span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">...or.</span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">O min...do".</span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">Ca...as".</span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">Ao enc...izou.</span></p> 
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">Também parti...o.</span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">Ao a...ócio".</span></p> 
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>Debate: reforma na CLT</strong></span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">O min...s.</span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">Ao...disse.</span></p>
   <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">O m...o o país". &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></p>  <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style="font-size:12px;">(Fernanda Loureiro)</span></p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </div>
 <DIV style="vertical-align:bottom !important">
  <!-- FACEBOOK CURTIR --> <!-- <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
  <fb:like layout="button_count" show_faces="true" width="80"></fb:like>-->
  <iframe class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.tst.jus.br/noticias/-/asset_publisher/89Dk/content/{rss=true}&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&width=25&height=25&locale=pt_BR" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none;border:0;margin-left:0; overflow:hidden; width:95px; height:25px;horizontal-align:left;vertical-align:bottom;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
  <!-- TWITTAR --> <span style="margin-left:20px;"> <script type="text/javascript"> var endereco; endereco = window.location.href; document.write('<a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=' + endereco + '" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Presidente do TST diz que trabalho precisa ser valorizado sem perda de competitividade" data-count="horizontal" data-via="tst_oficial">Tweet</a>') </script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script> </span>
  <!-- OK FACEBOOK Recomendar --> <!--<iframe id="f2ee48257c" name="f1f8d54994" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden; height: 20px; width: 200px;" title="Like this content on Facebook." class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=228619377180035&amp;locale=pt_BR&sdk=joey&channel_url=http://www.facebook.com/TSTJus?fref=ts&version=18%23cb%3Df360a99c9c&origin=http://www.tst.jus.br/noticias&href=http://www.tst.jus.br/noticias%26relation%3Dparent.parent&node_type=link&width=150&font=arial&layout=button_count&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&send=true&extended_social_context=false&action=recommend" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>-->
  <iframe border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="fb_ltr" id="f2ee48257c" name="f1f8d54994" style="border:none;margin-left:0; overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:25px;horizontal-align:left;vertical-align:bottom;" allowTransparency="true" title="Enviar notícia no Facebook" class="fb_ltr" src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=228619377180035&locale=pt_BR&sdk=joey&channel_url=http://www.tst.jus.br/noticias%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Df360a99c9c%26origin%3Dhttp://www.tst.jus.br/noticias%26relation%3Dparent.parent&amp;href=http://www.tst.jus.br/noticias&node_type=link&amp;width=150&amp;font=arial&amp;layout=button_count&amp;colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&send=true&amp;extended_social_context=false&action=recommend"></iframe> 
  <!-- YOUTUBE --> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/tst" target="_blank"> <img src="http://www.tst.jus.br/image/image_gallery?uuid=49d1dfeb-fba6-48be-9984-c2ba7dac709e&groupId=10157&t=1359131490760" border="0" title="Inscrição no Canal Youtube do TST" alt="Inscrição no Canal Youtube do TST"></a>
 </DIV> </br>
</description>
```

I've already tried using regex, but could only get the first paragraph (`'#<p[^>]*>(.*)</p>#isU'`). With SimpleXmlElement, DOM, I keep getting errors (I don't really know much about them, but they seem the best way to do it) and finally HTMLPurifier, which filters everything and returns nothing relevant.

Here is how I did it at the end (following Puggan Se's suggestion):

```
$i=0;
$feed= '<XML STRING>'; //The whole XML string here
$dom = new DOMDocument(); //declaring DOMDocument
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; //removing spaces
$dom->loadXML($feed, LIBXML_PARSEHUGE); //LIBXML_PARSEHUGE for long XMLs
$dom->formatOutput = true; // for a nice output ??

$xml = new DOMXPath($dom); //declaring the XPath

$xml->registerNamespace('a','http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'); //getting the namespace from the XML

//evaluates
$source = $xml->evaluate("//channel/title");
$titles = $xml->evaluate("//item/title");
$links = $xml->evaluate("//item/link");
$dates = $xml->evaluate("//item/dc:date");
$descriptions = $xml->evaluate("//item/description");

//echoing channel's title
 if($source->length > 0) {
 $source= $source->item(0)->nodeValue;
 echo $source. '<br /><br />';
 }

//echoing the items
 foreach($titles as $title) {
  echo "{$titles->item($i)->nodeValue}<br /><br />";
  echo "{$links->item($i)->nodeValue}<br /><br />";
  echo "{$dates->item($i)->nodeValue}<br /><br />";
  //filtering only <p><span> text from <description>
  $description = "{$descriptions->item($i)->nodeValue} ";
  $description = mb_convert_encoding($conteudo, 'html-entities', 'utf-8'); 
  unset($domtmp);
  $domtmp = new DOMDocument();
  $domtmp->loadHTML($description );
  $xmltmp = new DOMXPath($domtmp);
  $desc= $xmltmp->evaluate("//p/span");
   foreach($desc as $node) {
    echo "<p>{$node->nodeValue}</p>";
   }
  $i++;
 }
```

Do you know how I could improve it?

Thank you very much, for the help!

Comment: is $description XML? can you parse it and then use xpath to fetch all P, and then just echo the content of each P

Comment: please post at least a valid snippet of your XML, I can't access that link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why you couldn't access it, but i've edited the question to include the part of the XML that matters. Thank you!